# Using Neo4j Java API property Container

Tags: java, neo4j, gephi, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to update a apoc plugin for Gephi, so that I can send weights from Neo4j to Gephi. This is the original version [of the plugin](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.1/src/main/java/apoc/gephi/Gephi.java). What was my thinking that I could easily rearrange

```
private Map<String, Object> data(PropertyContainer pc, Map<String, Map<String, Object>> colors) {
    if (pc instanceof Node) {
        Node n = (Node) pc;
        String labels = Util.labelString(n);
        Map<String, Object> attributes = map("label", caption(n), "TYPE", labels);
        attributes.putAll(positions());
        attributes.putAll(color(labels,colors));
        return map(idStr(n), attributes);
    }
    if (pc instanceof Relationship) {
        Relationship r = (Relationship) pc;
        String type = r.getType().name();
        Map<String, Object> attributes = map("label", type, "TYPE", type);
        attributes.putAll(map("source", idStr(r.getStartNode()), "target", idStr(r.getEndNode()), "directed", true));
        attributes.putAll(color(type, colors));
        return map(String.valueOf(r.getId()), attributes);
    }
    return map();
}
```

to something like this, where I would change how relationship is being parsed, and add a weight to return

```
private Map<String, Object> data(PropertyContainer pc, Map<String, Map<String, Object>> colors) {
    if (pc instanceof Node) {
        Node n = (Node) pc;
        String labels = Util.labelString(n);
        Map<String, Object> attributes = map("label", caption(n), "TYPE", labels);
        attributes.putAll(positions());
        attributes.putAll(color(labels,colors));
        return map(idStr(n), attributes);
    }
    if (pc instanceof Relationship) {
        Relationship r = (Relationship) pc;
        String type = r.getType().name();
        String weight = r.getProperty("weight");
        Map<String, Object> attributes = map("label", type, "TYPE", type);
        attributes.putAll(map("source", idStr(r.getStartNode()), "target", idStr(r.getEndNode()), "directed", false,"weight",weight));
        attributes.putAll(color(type, colors));
        return map(String.valueOf(r.getId()), attributes);
    }
    return map();
}
```

Now the problem occurs that I am a JAVA noob and have no idea how to interact with JAVA data types. I found this [documentation on property container](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html), where i found the `getProperty(String key)` method and I tried to use it, like above but got the next error

> /Users/Hal/Job/neo4j-apoc-procedures/src/main/java/apoc/gephi/Gephi.java:81:
>   error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
>               String weight = r.getProperty("weight");

I think this is some basic JAVA problem, but I have no idea how to debug this. I also tried `String weight = r.getProperty(weight);` but got the same error. Help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead try`Object weight = r.getProperty("weight");` The documentation says `getProperty` returns Object.

A string is an object. But an object is not (necessarily) a string.